# Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubunut/images: on server misbehaving

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-build

I have deployed minikube using the following link 
https://gist.github.com/edrex/b54023fc9dbe8d21c0c81f5cce523ede in My local machine and when i try to build a docker image using `docker build -t hello-node:v1 .` as per this link

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-your-nodejs-application

it throws the following error

`Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1 : FROM node:6.9.2
Pulling repository docker.io/library/node
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/node/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 192.168.122.1:53: server misbehaving`

Any help would be off great use 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you checked your proxy/firewall settings? Is your DNS setup correctly? Try to set it to 8.8.8.8 and see if that helps.

Comment: i tried changing the /etc/resolv.conf in minikube using minikube ssh then it worked but after some time i again land into the same issue upon checking i see the /etc/resolv.conf values are reverted back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `$ eval $(minikube docker-env)` in the current terminal to point to the docker instance in minikube.

Comment: Yes i have tried the above commands after pointing the docker instance to minikube